# Squish Hook into an AUT that has a Windows console and Qt window

Tags: windows, qt, squish

When trying to start an AUT with the toolkit set to Qt and 'Hook into sub-processes launched by the application' set, I have to launch the application (which is a windows application that launches a process to set up a Qt window) using the dllpreload.exe provided by Squish to attach to the Qt window. Doing this doesn't show the windows console and just launches the Qt window. This hooks into Qt successfully...

When setting `testSettings.setWrappersForApplication("application", ("Windows", "Qt"))` or `testSettings.setWrappersForApplication("application", ("Windows"))`, it fails to hook onto the Qt window as a Qt window and doesn't recognise the Qt components.

Is there anyway for squish to recognise the windows console as 'Windows' and the Qt window as 'Qt'?

Comment: Do you have a native Windows application which launches a Qt application, or is it the other way round? Does the native Windows application show any UI itself?

Comment: A native windows application which launches a Qt application; to be more specific, the windows application reads a script file and loads Qt components stored in DLLs then creates a Qt Window from a .ui file. The Windows application is a console application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use case of hooking into a Qt application which is a subprocess of a native Windows application is documented in [a Knowledge Base article](https://kb.froglogic.com/display/KB/Article+-+Automating+Qt+applications+started+from+Qt+or+Windows+applications). The easiest approach to this is:

1. Rename the original executable of the Qt application, say `myqtapp.exe` to the same name but add an underscore at the end, i.e. `myqtapp_.exe`.
2. Rename the `dllpreload.exe` program shipped with Squish to `myqtapp.exe`.

That way, your Windows program will unknowingly call `dllpreload.exe`, which will then deduce the file name of the original application from its own file name (it'll just add an underscore).

The `dllpreload.exe` program is not a perfect proxy though, so it may be that your Windows application notices that it's not interacting with the real AUT. In that case, it may be easier to modify the Windows application so that it explicitly prepends `dllpreload.exe` to the command line which is used to start the Qt application.

You could do this conditionally such that it's only done when the Windows application is launched via Squish. This situation can be detected by testing for the existence of the `SQUISH_PREFIX` environment variable.

Comment: Using dllpreload in the application itself launched the Qt window, but Squish didn't hook into to it as expected. Following the linked knowledge base article (using 'Squish::installBuiltinHook();'), I was able to use both the windows console and hook into the Qt window as I would have hoped. There still seems to be some issue with Squish recognising the QtWindow on 'waitForObject' when I tried to send it a QCloseEvent, but at least Squish is recognising the components of the window.